# how to get elements having particular name from a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NSMutableArray consisting of several elements. From this array I want to pick out only those elements that contains the word "example" in any form (words such as exampleId, putexample or getexampleId).

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm no expert but I think this is a great time to look at the NSPredicate class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filterUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` method:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = ...
NSString *nameSearch = ...

[myArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS %@", nameSearch]];
```

For more information about `NSPredicate`, check out the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1).